# Node.js - Python-shell

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, cmd, windows-10

I've been having some issues with installing python-shell.

**WARNING!** I'm a novice at Javascript however I eat, drink and sleep Python. I would love to include Python in whatever program I'm working on (if it's practical).

I am creating some desktop applications and would love the make them look modern via a little Html, CSS, Javascript spice.

**Checking my Node version:**

```
C:\nodejs\py-js\test>npm -v6.4.1
```

**Installing Python-Shell via npm:**

```
C:\nodejs\py-js\test>npm install python-shell
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\py-js\test\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\py-js\test\package.json'
npm WARN test No description
npm WARN test No repository field.
npm WARN test No README datanpm WARN test No license field.
python-shell@1.0.6 added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1 package in 1.827s found 0 vulnerabilities
```

**npm test**

```
C:\nodejs\py-js\test2>npm test
npm ERR! path C:\nodejs\py-js\test2\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\nodejs\py-js\test2\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kurup\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-19T20_15_56_010Z-debug.log
```

HELP! :(

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the package. Run this to create your `package.json` file:

```
npm init
```

Then you can define your test script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you are trying to run your program with the `npm test` command line.

This is the [npm command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/test.html) to run a specific script, in this case the "test" script that you should provide in your *package.json* file. Since you do not create a *package.json* at all, this command fails.

For exemple, if you use `npm init` to generate a *package.json* file, you will get this default "test" script:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

To launch your program, you can use:

```
node test.js
```

Or you could add a "start" script in your *package.json* and use:

```
npm start
```